# How can I setup the distribution build to get watchkit App working?

Tags: xcode, bundle, watchkit, ios-provisioning

My watchkit app is working ok when I run it with the wildcard developer profile. When I run it with distribution profile, the Watch app says : 
**Failed to authenticate**. I have then gone on to build unique *Bundle IDs* for each app. Then updated the *Provisioning Profiles* to use the new *Bundle IDs*. When I try to build again it is still not installing the watchkit App.

I do not see any logs pertaining to this error in the devices window. I have tried switching the "Skip Install" to no for the watchkit app target. Here is a screenshot of the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Xcode 8 where provisioning is done automatically and should finally let you stop worrying